# Two ways to make a nested list. What is the difference?

Tags: html

Here are two ways to nest one list inside another. Are they both really correct? And is there a semantic difference between them?

```html
<ol>
  <li><p>List item 1.</p></li>
  <li>
    <p>List item 2.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
    <ul>
      <li><p>Nested-list item 1.</p></li>
      <li>
        <p>Nested list item 2.</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><p>List item 1.</p></li>
  <li>
    <p>List item 2.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li><p>Nested-list item 1.</p></li>
    <li>
      <p>Nested list item 2.</p>
      <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code block is semantically incorrect. Semantically, the right way to nest a list is, to include the nested list as a child element of the `<li>` tag.

[W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) is a great tool to check if your code is semantically correct and fix errors.

Hope this clear things up